# Mail authentication fails

Tags: java

```
final String to = maildata.mailadres;

      // Mailadres van
      final String from = "right@email.com";
  // host voor e-mail
  String host = "###.##.#.#";

  Properties props = new java.util.Properties();
  props.put("mail.smtp.host", "###.##.#.#"); 
  props.put("mail.smtp.port", "##"); 
  props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false");
  props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");


  // Setup mail server
  props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

  Session session = javax.mail.Session.getInstance( props, 
             new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                   return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication("####", "#####");
           }
             });
```

For some reason this authentication for active directory fails (obviously the host etc are correct)
It does send the mail correctly but just ignores the authentication

Comment: Can you please elaborate how Active Directory is connected to your SMTP server authentication? And what are yours expectations?